# how to disable blinking cursor in opensuse 12.2 kde virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, kde, opensuse, cursor

I have just installed the newest OpenSUSE 12.2 with KDE into my VirtualBox.
I have one problem. When my cursor is animated (watches and other), it's blinking.
How can I disable it?

Thanks